# How to detect the path to the application root?

Tags: php

I'm trying to dynamically detect the root directory of my page in order to direct to a specific script.

```
echo ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
```

It prints /myName/folder/index.php

I'd like to use in a html-file to enter a certain script like this:

```
<a href="<?php $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'lib/logout.php'?>">log out</a>
```

This seems to be in bad syntax, the path is not successfully resolved.

What's the proper approach to detect the path to logout.php?

The same question in different words:

How can I reliably achieve the path to the root directory (which contains my index.php) from ANY subdirectory? No matter if the html file is in /lib/subfolder or in /anotherDirectory, I want it to have a link directing to /lib/logout.php

On my machine it's supposed to be http://localhost/myName/folder (which contains index.php and all subdirectories), on someone else's it might be http://localhost/project

How can I detect the path to application root?

Comment: It's in /home/myName/alphp/folder

Comment: you cannot detect path to logout.php. to the site root you mean?

Comment: the question is **extremely** vague. Dude, you have to provide exact examples of what you need.

Answer (score 2):

After some clarification from the OP it become possible to answer this question.

If you have some configuration file being included in all php scripts, placed in the app's root folder you can use this file to determine your application root:

```
$approot = substr(dirname(__FILE__),strlen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']));
```

`__FILE__` constant will give you filesystem path to this file. If you subtract DOCUMENT_ROOT from it, the rest will be what you're looking for. So it can be used in your templates:

```
<a href="<?php echo $approot?>/lib/logout.php">log out</a>
```

Comment: The OP said dynamically determine the root.  It might differ, for example, in development and production.

Comment: Exactly. It's not always the same path, it depends on the location of the invoking file

Comment: @auge do not call it root then. if you want relative path, so you have to ask for this.

Comment: When calling from index.php (which is in root), <a href="lib/logout.php"> ist fine. But when the invoking script is already in lib, the resolved url is http://localhost/myName/folder/lib/lib/logout.php

Comment: @auge any reason you cannot use `/myName/folder/lib/logout.php`?

Comment: myName is my name. On someone else's machine it will be http://localhost/someonesName

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are looking for the URL not the Path

```
<a href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>lib/logout.php">log out</a>
```

and you are not echoing the variable in your example.

Comment: @auge: Change your file's extension from .html to .php. PHP is not parsed with .html file

Comment: @auge: What is the extension name of file this code being executed in?

Comment: This is really the closest I get to the script in question. Final problem: The link actually is http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>lib/logout.php, so the variable is not properly resolved

Comment: Sorry, the variable would be resolved, but it's the echo which does not show up. The php-code doesn't seem to run

Answer (score 1):

Your DOCUMENT_ROOT is local to your machine - so it might end up being c:/www or something, useful for statements like REQUIRE or INCLUDE but not useful for links.

If you've got a page accessible on the web - linking back to a document on C: is going to try and get that drive from the local machine.

So for links, you should just be able to go /lib/logout.php with the initial slash taking you right to the top of your web accessible structure.

Your page, locally - might be in c:/www/myprojects/project1/lib/logout.php but the site itself might be at http://www.mydomain.com/lib/project.php

Answer (score 0):

Frameworks like [Symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/) offer a sophisticated routing mechanism which allows you to write link urls like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo url_for('lib/logout.php') ?>">log out</a>
```

It has tons of possibilities, which are described in [the tutorial](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_2/Propel/en/05).

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<a href="/lib/logout.php'?>">log out</a>
```

This jumps to the root directly.

Answer (score 0):

`DOCUMENT_ROOT` refers to the physical path on the webserver. There is no generic way to detect the http path fragment. Quite often you can however use `PHP_SELF` or `REQUEST_URI`

Both depend on how the current script was invoked. If the current request was to the index.php in a /whatever/ directory, then try the raw REQUEST_URI string. Otherwise it's quite commonly:

```
<?= dirname($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]) . "/lib/logout.php" ?>
```

It's often best if you use a configurable constant for such purposes however. There are too many ifs  going on here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to figure this out for PHP as well. In asp.net, we have Request.ApplicationPath, which makes this pretty easy.

For anyone out there fluent in PHP who is trying to help, this code does what the OP is asking, but in asp.net:

```
public string AppUrl
{
    get
    {
        string appUrl = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + Request.ApplicationPath;
        if (appUrl.Substring(appUrl.Length - 1) != "/")
        {
            appUrl += "/";
        }
        // Workaround for sockets issue when using VS Built-int web server
        appUrl = appUrl.Replace("0.0.0.0", "localhost");
        return appUrl;
    }
}
```

I couldn't figure out how to do this in PHP, so what I did was create a file called globals.php, which I stuck in the root. It has this line:

```
$appPath = "http://localhost/MyApplication/";
```

It is part of the project, but excluded from source control. So various devs just set it to whatever they want and we make sure to never deploy it. This is probably the effort the OP is trying to skip (as I skipped with my asp.net code).

I hope this helps lead to an answer, or provides a work-around for PHPers out there.